# What resources does a population use when upgrading their homes?

Tags: anno-1404, anno-1404-venice

While the population constantly consumes resources, they also use some resources when they graduate to the next prosperity level.

For instance, I know that to reach level 2 Oriental citizens have to consume at least 1 mosaic for each house.  It seems like the Occidental citizens at least consume tools and stone, but maybe glass as well.

What resources does each level of population require to upgrade their homes, both Occident and Oriental?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Oriental** upgrades per house needs:

- 1 ton of wood
- 1 ton of tools
- 4 tons of mosaic

**Occidental** upgrades per house needs:

Peasant to Citizen

- 1 ton of tools
- 1 ton of wood

Citizen to Patrician

- 1 ton of tools
- 1 ton of wood
- 4 tons of stone

Patrician to Nobleman

- 1 ton of tools
- 1 ton of wood
- 3 tons of stone
- 3 tons of glass

Nomad to Envoy

- 1 ton of tools
- 1 ton of wood
- 3 tons of mosaic